# old rsync and spaces in filenames

Tags: linux, macos, bash, rsync

Source directory is determined like so:

```
SHOW=${PWD##*/}
SRC=wells@server.com:"/mnt/bigfish/video/TV/${SHOW}/"
```

So it comes out something like:

```
wells@server.com:/mnt/bigfish/video/TV/The Name Of the Show With Spaces/
```

Then trying to run rsync like so:

```
rsync -avz -e ssh "${SRC}" .
```

But it tells me that ""/mnt/bigfish/video/TV/The" is not a directory, ""/mnt/bigfish/video/TV/Name" is not a directory, etc, for however many space-delimited words are in the name of the source directory.

How can I rectify this egregiously annoying issue?

**UPDATE** I'm running this on OS 10.6, and I ended up string-replacing spaces with escaped spaces like so:

```
SRC=wells@kittenfactory.com:"/mnt/bigfish/video/TV/${SHOW// /\ }/"
```

Answer (score 7):

From the [rsync manual](http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html):

> -s, --protect-args
>                 This option sends all filenames and most options to  the 
>   remote
>                 rsync without allowing the remote shell to interpret them. 
>   This
>                 means that spaces are not split in names, and  any 
>   non-wildcard
>                 special  characters  are  not  translated  (such  as ~, $, ;, &,
>                 etc.).  Wildcards are expanded  on  the  remote  host  by 
>   rsync
>                 (instead of the shell doing it).

Comment: There is no such option in the Darwin 10.4 build of rsync in Snow Leopard.

Comment: @wells: then you should probably get a version more current than the six year old one that Apple decided to ship you: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/10.4/man1/rsync.1.html?useVersion=10.4

Answer (score 4):

As your question is dedicated to OS X, according to the [Apple rsync manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/rsync.1.html) you can accomplish this using either simple quotes or the wildcard `?`:

```
rsync -av host:'file\ name\ with\ spaces' /dest
rsync -av host:file?name?with?spaces /dest
```

Just had to do this and using the simple quotes works perfectly:

```
rsync -r --partial --progress --exclude=".cvs" --exclude=".svn" --exclude=".git" --rsh=ssh root@datakeep.local:'/volume1/devel/__To\ SORT/___XXXXX\ Saves\ 2011-04' ./Saves2011
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
rsync -avz -e ssh "wells@server.com:\"/mnt/bigfish/video/TV/${SHOW}/\""
```

So set:

```
SRC=wells@server.com:\"/mnt/bigfish/video/TV/${SHOW}/\"
```

At least, here on Debian it works like a charm, no OS 10 available to test with here.

Comment: Yeah, -s and manual escaping are the recommended workarounds. From the manual: "If you need to transfer a filename that contains whitespace, you can  either  specify the --protect-args (-s) option, or you’ll need to escape the whitespace in a way that the remote shell will understand."

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on OSX if you're dealing with arguments in a script:

```
ESCAPED_SRC="$(echo "$SRC" | tr ' ' '\\ ')"
ESCAPED_DEST="$(echo "$DEST" | tr ' ' '\\ ')"
rsync -ravP "$ESCAPED_SRC" "$ESCAPED_DEST"
```